# Filter and count with django

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a Post and Vote tables.
Each post can be either liked or disliked (this is the post_type).

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("title"), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("content"), unique=True)
    ip = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("ip"), max_length=15)


class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    post_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('post_type'))
```

I want to get posts and annotate each post with number of likes.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what `post_type` is doing? How does that field record a like or dislike?

Comment: It is a choice filed: CHOICES=((1, 'LIKE'), (2, 'DISLIKE'))

Comment: Only 'likes'? or 'dislikes' also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a function in Post model and call this whenever you need the count.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def likes_count(self):
        return self.vote_set.filter(post_type=1).count()
```

Use it like this:

```
p = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
print p.likes_count()
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a method to the `Post` class that fetches this count, as shown by @sachin-gupta. However this will generate one extra query for every post that you fetch. If you are fetching posts and their counts in bulk, this is not desirable.

You could annotate the posts in bulk but I don't think your current model structure will allow it, because you cannot filter within an annotation. You could consider changing your structure as follows:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract vote model.
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class LikeVote(Vote)
    pass


class DislikeVote(Vote)
    pass
```

i.e., instead of storing likes and dislikes in one model, you have a separate model for each. Now, you can annotate your posts in bulk, in a single query:

```
from django.db.models import Count    

posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(Count('likevote_set'))

for post in posts:
    print post.likevote__count
```

Of course, whether or not this is feasible depends on the architecture of the rest of your app, and how many "vote types" you are planning to have. However if you are going to be querying the vote counts of posts frequently then you will need to try and avoid a large number of database queries.